# Proof verification that series $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{10^{\frac{1}{n+1}}} $ converges

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

Proof that the series converges

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{10^{1/(n+1)}} $$

My proof:
$$
\left(\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{10^{1/(n+1)}}\right)^{1/n} = \frac{(-1)^{1+1/n}}{10^{1/(n^2+n)}}
$$
when n goes to infinity we get:

$$\frac{-1\cdot 1}{1} = -1 < 1 \implies\text{series is convergent}$$

After retry with absolute value:

$$\left|\frac{-1\cdot 1}{1}\right| = 1 \implies \text{we don't know if it converges}  $$

Comment: You applied the root test in the wrong way...

Comment: Please [don't use `\frac` in exponents or limits of integrals](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5057/290189). It looks bad and confusing, and it rarely appears in professional mathematics typesetting.

Comment: **[Reminder]** : The root test states that for any sequence $(a_{n})_{n}$, if $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_{n}|}=L<1 $$ then the series given by $\sum a_{n}$ converges. Therefore, do not forget the **absolute** .

Comment: @GAUSS1860 how do you know it converges then, because it becomes 1. I also edited the question.

Comment: Attempt the Alternate Series Test, what do you think of the limit of $\displaystyle\frac{1}{10^{1/(n+1)}}$ as $n\to\infty$ ? What do we say if the limit is different from $0$? What can we also say about $(-1)^{n}$? Then and only then you will know if the series converges or not :)

Comment: @GAUSS1860 it's $\frac{1}{1}$ right ?

Comment: Indeed, so the limit condition fails in the alternate series test, then you conclude by the $n^{th}$ term divergence test that.... and you are done.

Comment: @GAUSS1860 I see, the limit is no zero, so it diverges..

Comment: yep, and that is true since limit $(-1)^{n}$ doesn't exist and limit of $\displaystyle\frac{1}{10^{1/(n+1)}}$ is different from zero when $n\to+\infty$.

Comment: @GAUSS1860 Would the argument that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(-1)^n$ doesn't converge be enought for this proof ?

Comment: No, since this might not be sufficient for other examples like $\sum (-1)^{n} / n$ where $\lim_{n\to\infty}\displaystyle\frac{1}{n} =0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all,
$10^{1/(n+1)}
=e^{\ln(10)/(n+1)}
\approx 1+\ln(10)/(n+1)
\lt 2$
for $n > \ln(10)$
so the fractions are between
$\frac12$ and $1$ for
$n > 3$.

Therefore the sum is neither
absolutely nor conditionally
convergent.

Comment: Wouldn't it suffice to just say $1\lt10^{1/(n+1)}\le10^{1/(0+1)}=10$